# Trying to install 18.04.2 on a Dell Latitude E6500 with legacy BIOS

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, dell

I ran Ubuntu 18.04.2 from the "live" disc with no problems. The installation appeared to go without a hitch - twice. However, after the installation completes, it doesn't not boot. All I get is a blinking cursor up in the left corner of the screen.

I followed instructions for boot repair. That also seemed to run fine from the "live" disc, but it did not solve the boot problem. From what I can tell, the Dell Latitude E6500 does not have a UEFI mode. There were some articles I read that suggested that that was the problem, but they offered no solution. How do I install Ubuntu on the Dell Latitude E6500 successfully? Perhaps there is a different version that will install.

Comment: Correct, it's BIOS so the classic installation is applicable. But it has a professional Nvidia Quadro NVS160m which requires additional proprietary drivers, the 340 version for legacy hardware to be precise.

Comment: I appreciate your response. Can you point me to the information on how to install the proper drivers for the Nvidia Quadro NVS160m. I am a complete newbie so I am not sure what you mean by the "340 version for legacy hardware". Would you be willing to clarify that for me please?

Comment: It's already installed so now you need to make the Grub menu appear so you can boot with an additional parameter, `nomodeset`, but I don't remember how to do it with BIOS/Legacy.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to figure out how to configure it to use the Nvidia drivers. I am installing some updates now. I am crossing my fingers that it will work once it reboots. I'll let you know. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: OK - well, it didn't work. I guess I will try MINT instead.

Comment: You do what you want. However, Mint is off-topic here.

Comment: Mint - same problem. Live Disc works, installation goes perfectly - won't boot. Dell Latitude E6500 passes all diagnostics.

Comment: Again, Mint is off-topic here.